# What is rd and gm in oscillator circuits and how to set them up in LTspice?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, oscillator, ltspice, feedback

I have a lab experiment about Oscillator Circuits. We were given a phase-shift oscillator circuit. In the given variables are: rd (r sub d) = 40k and gm (g sub m) = 6000 mS. We are supposed to use a 2n5458 transistor in the amplifier part of the circuit. My question is, how, where or what component do I assign the values of gm and rd to in LTspice?

I searched around and found out that rd and Rd are different, so I'm confused now.

EDIT:

2n5458 is a N-channel JFET

Here is the schematic diagram of the circuit:

[image]

We were only given PowerPoint presentations about Feedback Concepts and Oscillator Concepts and it does not explain in depth about what gm and rd are. All I know is that gm is a factor of Voltage Gain (A) in feedback concepts and I know that Rd is Drain Resistance.

> A = (rd)(RL) where RL is load resistance

EDIT2:

I'm so sorry about the mix-up, here is the schematic diagram:

[image]

Comment: 1) show the schematic and testbench. 2) what type of transistor is a 2N5458 (include a link to its datasheet). 3) you have to **KNOW** what gm, rd and Rd mean before you can do this assignment. gm and rd are **small signal parameters**, these have been explained to you in a class, course or in a book. This isn't something you can understand without training. It goes to far to explain gm and rd here so get studying!

Comment: thank you, kind sir! I already updated the post

Comment: *2n5458 is a n-channel JFET* Correct! Then why is there an NPN in your schematic?

Comment: oh my, thank you sir for being patient with me

Comment: The transconuctance is gm=6000mS...are you sure?

Comment: yes I'm sure, it is stated in the lab guide

Comment: The oscillator shall have gm = 6000 mS, rd = 40 kohms

Comment: The datasheet states that the 2N5458 has a typical forward transmittance of 4000 umhos = 4000 uS. That's **micro** and more than 1000x times smaller than requested.

Comment: okay, so gm value depends on the transistor? I think my instructor did that on purpose so that we will have to manually set it. But how?

Comment: The transconductance parameter is a property of the transistor and can be set by selecting a suitable quiescent current. Are you familiar with transistor basics?

Comment: hmmmm okay, yes I'm somewhat familiar (not confident) with transistor basics. But what value do I change in LT Spice to set the given transconductance and quiescent current?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, I just got a notification from my instructor that the transconductance is 6000uS not 6000mS. Mygod he's giving me headaches

Comment: The 2N5458 Jfet is obsolete. Why didn't  your teacher pick a modern one? Did your teacher or textbook explain what is the function of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Under ideal conditions, the feedback network (3rd-order highpass) has an attenuation factor of 1/29 at a frequency where the phase shift is -180deg (oscillation condition).

Hence, the gain of the stage (determined by gm, RD and the input impedance of the feedback network) must be at least -29.

Of course, for a safe start of oscillation (and due to some uncertainties and tolerances) the design should consider a gain of app -(30...35).

Answer (score -1):

If "gm" is the energy input, and "rd" is the lossy component in the system/resonator, then these two values are crucial to oscillator behavior.

Comment: Not sure how this helps OP in any way.